# Python classes and unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, subclass

I'm working through python for rookies, and i've come across a question in which I had to make a class, and subclasses which is fine(i presume ive done it right)

but I now have to include some testing with python `unittest` module and i can't figure out how to implement this, any help would be appreciated.

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 0

    def withdraw(self,amount):
        if self.balance - amount <= 0:
            print "Overdrawn, please try another option."            
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
            return self.balance
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

    def interest(self, amount):
        percent = self.balance / 100.0 * amount
        self.balance = self.balance + percent
        return self.balance


class CreditAccount(BankAccount):
    def withdraw(self,amount):
        if self.balance - amount <= 0:
            self.balance = self.balance - amount - 5
            print "Overdrawn, you have been charged £5 for this."
            return self.balance
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
            return self.balance

class StudentAccount(BankAccount):

    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 500

    def withdraw(self, amount):       
        if self.balance - amount >= -3000:
            self.balance -= amount
            return self.balance
        else:
            print "£3000 Overdraft limit reached"
            return self.balance


account = BankAccount()
account1 = CreditAccount()
account2 = StudentAccount()
account2.deposit(500)
```

Comment: I can't figure out where to start on this unfortinatly, i've read the chapter but I can't make much sence of it

Comment: Maybe reading over the docs will help: http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#basic-example

Comment: I've read it but prehaps I'll spend some more time on it, try and make a start and post from there, thankyou for the help

Comment: @user1289022: you need to be a *lot* more explicit. What can't you make much sense of? There's a lot there.

Comment: First of all what Im suppose to be testing for with this, Its not really specified and I kinda hoped someone would have an idea based on my code. The task simply states 'include some testing' with the unittest module.

Comment: The testing includes different deposits and different types of accounts. Try different types of input for your program and see if it produces correct output. This is to see if your program is correct and does not fail.

Comment: Voting to close as "not a real question". As others have pointed out, no question has been asked (and even the comments are fairly vague).

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387326/unit-testing-videos-or-podcasts will help?

Comment: Thanks, by all means close this topic. Sorry for not being specific enough, next time I'll endeavour to improve my posts.

Comment: @user1289022 http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#basic-example this should probably help you. Its quite directly presented.

Answer (score 1):

let me just get you started..

```
my_account = BankAccount()
balance = my_account.deposit(1000) # can also be accessed by my_account.balance
```

hopefully you can take it from here